# Is @Configuration optional for JavaConfig classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

**NOTE:** This question also appears in the Spring forums (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/748870-is-configuration-optional-for-javaconfig-classes), but I was encourage to post this on SOF too due to the upcoming deprecation of these forums, in favour of SOF.

---

I have a question about Java classes that are used for Java-based Spring configuration. It is well documented in Spring documentation, JavaDoc, and posts from other blogs and forums that these classes should be annotated with @Configuration. However, what I'm wondering about is if it is actually mandatory for them to be annotated with @Configuration.

I am writing a REST server with Spring. I am able to refer to my configuration class through web.xml and the class is able to set-up my Spring application context just fine without the class being annotated with @Configuration. Same story with my test code: all my tests are annotated with @ContextConfiguration and can point to my JavaConfig class (via the classes attribute) even without the JavaConfig class being annotated with @Configuration. I should also note that my JavaConfig class inherits from other configuration classes through the @Import annotation and those downstream configuration classes are too not annotated with @Configuration.

This all bears me the question: is @Configuration really just an optional attribute? Perhaps we would need it if we have an XML context file that uses  to find @Configuration-annotated classes via DI/autowiring to use for Spring context configuration. But that is not the case for me; I can't just automatically pull in all classes annotated with @Configuration since I have separate configuration for my server setup and my test setup.

Can someone please confirm my thoughts about whether @Configuration is truely optional? If so, then shouldn't this fact be reflected in the Spring documentation or in the JavaDoc of that annotation? Thank you.

Comment: I think the spring forum clearly answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you clearly refer to every configuration class (using `web.xml`, `WebApplicationInitializer`, `@ContextConfiguration`, `<import>`, `@Import`) then yes, the annotation does seem optional.

But when you are using component scanning, then you can easily add classes annotated with `@Configuration` to the mix, without ever having to refer to them from elsewhere. 
When you have a lot of configuration to do, this really comes in handy.

Another issue is that I am pretty sure that if you have not annotated a configuration class with `@Configuration`, then `@Conditional` from Spring 4 will not work correctly